# Looping through directories not behaving as expected

Tags: c#

`directory` is a path, ie `L:\\H435431 Project Name` which may or may not contain a sub directory named `2-Storage`, or `2-STORAGE`.  If this directory is discovered, I'd like to get a list of its sub directories and test to see if it contains `! Issued Packages`.

When I step through this code, `subdirectories` returns the expected array of folders and `containsStorage` is correctly set to `true`. In turn, `d` correctly reflects the directory name i'd like to search next, `L:\\H435431 Project Name\\2-Storage`.  **`ad` never gets assigned the value of `Directory.GetDirectories(d)` and the directory is never searched.  Why is this?**

```
string[] subirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
            foreach (string d in subirectories)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(d, @"2-Storage", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    containsStorage = true;
                    foreach (string ad in Directory.GetDirectories(d))
                    {
                        if (Regex.IsMatch(ad, @"! Issued Packages", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                        {
                            containsIssued = true;
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if SubSubDirectories is empty for us if there is nothing in there then there is nothing to iterate through.

```
   string[] subirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);
                foreach (string d in subirectories)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(d, @"2-Storage", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        containsStorage = true;
                        string[] subSubDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
                        foreach (string ad in subSubDirectories)
                        {
                            if (Regex.IsMatch(ad, @"! Issued Packages", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                            {
                                containsIssued = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                }
```

Comment: That is the problem.  subSubDirectories IS empty, howver, `d` does contain a string value representing a directory (which is set during the foreach iteration).  for some reason, suSubDirectories value does not get assigned.  There should be values as there are directories in this tree.

Comment: I know see you pulled the assignment out of the If condition, and yes, it works now.  Why is that?  thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, may require some experimenting to get a concise answer but good practice is to assign everything to a variable before using it in a loop such as the use of subSubDirectories. This especially allows easier debugging using break points.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the solution or mark as solved.